# Does Code Splitting improves start time in Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Since 4 years now I have a project set up like this:

```
// App
require('./src/app/xxxxx')(app);
require('./src/app/xxx')(app);

// Landing
require('./src/landing/xxxx')(landing);
require('./src/landing/xx')(landing);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
exports.landing = functions.https.onRequest(landing);
```

So, as you can see, in the same code/project, I have `app` and `landing`.

`app` has some functions that loads TONS of external dependencies. The start up time is around 2 seconds (huge!).

`landing` has only 2 functions inside, and it doesn't use any external dependency. Just 1 query to Firestore, and that's it.

My question now: Due to both functions are in the same project, does `landing` start up time get affected by all the external dependencies that I have for `app`?

Should I split the code in 2 different projects, so I have 1 "landing project" with few code&dependencies for `landing` (thus, fast start up time), and then other "app project" with big code&dependencies for `app`?

Will this improve the start up time for `landing`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.

I think the short answer is "yes". You should optimize functions, their dependencies and any (global) state based on the function's needs.

This gets to the heart of some of the mismatch between "serverless" and reality.

Beneath your Cloud (aka Firebase) Functions there is, of course, a server and a stack of runtimes. The main difference is in how much access you get to the underlying process|runtime. It's important to understand how, what you deploy, is deployed|run.

By way of contrast, App Engine (a pioneering "serverless" platform but one in which you can access more of the runtime) accepts similar units of deployment and, in response to requests, creates processes (instances). The developer is able to conceptualize an instance (of a server runtime), some state (possibly shared across instances) and **multiple** handlers.

With Cloud (Firebase) Functions, the developer is misled by "serverless" to believe that the service only runs individual functions.

Surprise, it doesn't.

Architecturally, "serverless" really is the same as before. Your code (the unit of what you deploy) is deployed atop the runtime. The difference is that you have less access to the underlying process (instance) and thus less access to the runtime('s capabilities).

IMO Functions-as-a-service is a better term than "serverless" but both mislead.

What does this mean for your question?

When you deploy multiple handlers as a single unit (with varied dependencies), each Cloud (Firebase) Function is an instance of the entire deployment but with only the designated Function exposed.

If you want to optimize, the instance for its designated function, you **should** minimize the imports per function. The only real consequences of this are that you will create more modules|deployments (one per function including its dependencies).

One important fact is that, given the above, functions can share (global) state. If an instance e.g. creates a Firestore client, or some other shared state, this **can** be shared across function invocations (across the shared instance).

If you have functions that share global state, it **may** make sense to keep them combined by instance. For example, if you have a function that gets Documents from Firestore and another function that sets (writes) Documents to Firestore, you **could** share the Firestore client across multiple (get|set) Functions on the instance. Not only sharing the import but sharing instance state.

You can (and should) prove this to yourself and prove your hypothesis, by splitting your functions across multiple deployments and observing their behavior.

Comment: Lovely long and detailed text, but the problem is that at the end you say: "try it yourself", and... to be honest, I asked it to not try it myself. Kind of... like... That's the reason behind why people ask questions hehehe.
I may have some free time to try this on March. I'll try it and I'll let you know. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Because you can prove the behavior by trying and then need not rely on trusting my explanation.

Comment: But, @DazWilkin, to be honest, I can't find what you are exactly proposing to try. I see you are saying that "I should minimize the imports per function". I already know that, and I already did it. But some imports are impossible to remove. My question still: "Should I split the code in different projects?"

Comment: Separate projects is unnecessary. Separate modules is all you need to do. You can't avoid required modules, of course. But, if function Foo needs import X and function Bar needs import Y. Then, instead of importing X and Y into a module that exports functions Foo and Bar. You can use 2 modules: one that imports only X for function Foo and a second that imports only Y for function Bar.

Comment: When you say "modules", you are referring to using `import` instead of `require`, right? Or are you referring to some Firebase/GoogleCloud concept?
My project doesn't have any `import`, it's all `require`, because the project was using Node 10 until few weeks ago. This question come up after I migrated everything to Node 14. Now I should be able to migrate everything, but it will be huge.